# change a column to character when using fread and file_list

Tags: r, fread

i need to read in multiple csv files and im using File list and Fread in R, but keep getting the following error, column 26 contains Phone numbers if that helps i want to change it to character

"Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) :
Internal error: column 26 of result is determined to be integer64 but maxType=='character' != REALSXP"

this is my code

```
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~##
SD_data <- data.table(NULL)

file_list <- list.files(path = SD_Data_feed, pattern="ldn - Data.*\\.csv", ignore.case=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  temp_data <- fread(file.path(SD_Data_feed, file_list[i]),
                 
                     select = c(1:4,6:33),
               
                      encoding = "UTF-8")
                  
   SD_data <- unique(rbind(SD_data, temp_data))}
```

i have tried a number of things :

colClasses=list(character=26) in between select and encoding

colClasses=c(26 = "character")in between select and encoding

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `colClasses=list(character=26)`.

Sample data and demo:

```r
write.csv(mtcars[1:3,], "mt.csv", row.names = FALSE)
fread("mt.csv")
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
fread("mt.csv", colClasses = list(character = 2))
#      mpg    cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <char> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  21.0      6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
# 2:  21.0      6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
# 3:  22.8      4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
```

To automate your code, I recommend a few things:

- `list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)` precludes the need to paste the directory (which we already knew) with the filename
- `lapply` into a list of frames;
- `rbindlist` to combine into one frame

```r
file_list <- list.files(path = SD_Data_feed, pattern = "ldn - Data.*\\.csv",
                        full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
SD_data <- lapply(file_list, fread, colClasses = list(character = 26),
                  select = c(1:4, 6:33), encoding = "UTF-8") |>
  rbindlist()
```

(The `|>` is R-4 or newer.)